# PHP PDO insert query error : Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

Hello I have a PHP script like that :

```
<?php 
require('includes/db-core.php');//My DB info
$dbh = mf_connect_db();//Creates a connection object
$newObjs = array();
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    array_push($newObjs,"data".$i);
}
try {
    for($i=0; i<sizeof($newObjs); $i++){
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO companies_table (data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");         
        $stmt2->bindParam(1, $newObjs[$i]);
        $stmt2->bindParam(2, $newObjs[$i]);
        $stmt2->bindParam(3, $newObjs[$i]);
        $stmt2->bindParam(4, $newObjs[$i]);
        $stmt2->bindParam(5, $newObjs[$i]);
        $stmt2->bindParam(6, $newObjs[$i]);
        $stmt2->execute();
    }
    echo "New Row successfully added";
}catch( Exception $e ){
    echo 'Query error : ', $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I get the following error: Query error : `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'data1' cannot be null` , but the data is inserted correctly and I don't know why this is hapening (Error + insertion).

All my table's fields are not null.

No one noticed this error from me :

```
try {
    for($i=0; i<sizeof($newObjs); $i++){
```

I forgot the $ sign, really Sorry but this is good for learning a point : thanks for all the users that gives answers but next time it's better to  check the post for errors first.

Thanks

Comment: var_dump $newObjs[$i] and let us know what you have got?

Comment: @AwladLiton, No need for that as it is clearly available from the above loop. It will be `data1 , data2 .... data6`

Comment: yes I checked and it is data1 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

As seem by the error into your db it seems that you cannot have column data1 null and in some point of the loop the same column seem to have null value.

Comment: But why, the array of data to insert has no empty values, I checked with the var_dump and all the array has data.

Comment: Have you tried putting the statement OUTSIDE of the loop? (Outside = before the loop)

Comment: The data are inserted , that is what making me crazy, but I get this error before.

Comment: Have you tried specify which tipe of data it is? like this: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Yes, $stmt2->bindParam(1, $newObjs[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR); same error.

Answer (score 0):

if you insist on using  for than in this example it should be:

```
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO companies_table (data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");  

    for($i=0; i<sizeof($newObjs); $i++){      
    $stmt2->bindParam(($i+1), $newObjs[$i]);

}
$stmt2->execute();
```

but in your case it look like bad idea overall

Comment: is it not the same as what I did?

Comment: @OussamaLord what you did is puting same thing $newObjs[$i] in all columns so you would end up with six rows, each of them having same value in all columns. if you have different types of columns you conversion will fail and you'll have an error (just as you did)

Comment: All my fields are Varchar type, I don't think it's an issue.

Comment: And the array I'm inserting has string data type : array(6) {
  '[0]=>
  string(5) "data0"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "data1"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "data2"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "data3"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "data4"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "data5"
}'